# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) and KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xa0000008

Tags: iphone, segmentation-fault

I have a problem that occurs from time to time and I can't  find 
the solution, can someone help me? Thanks

Here is the log of the crash and where the method is called

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00003fb0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Authentic                   0x00048ce2 -[JobsSubtitleView touchUp:] (JobsSubtitleView.m:172)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00026486 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
3   UIKit                           0x00032bf8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
4   UIKit                           0x00032bb4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
5   UIKit                           0x00032b92 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
6   UIKit                           0x00032902 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 486
7   UIKit                           0x0003307a -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 470
8   UIKit                           0x00031914 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 312
9   UIKit                           0x0003133a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 374
10  UIKit                           0x000076e6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 350
11  UIKit                           0x000070d2 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5802
12  GraphicsServices                0x00004f44 PurpleEventCallback + 876
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00083a28 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ +         32
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000839ca __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000825f0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00023f72 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00023e3a CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
18  GraphicsServices                0x0000411e GSEventRunModal + 150
19  UIKit                           0x00002472 UIApplicationMain + 1074
20  Authentic                   0x0006bbd0 main (main.m:17)
21  Authentic                   0x00002e8c start + 32


- (void) touchUp:(id)sender {
if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible]) {
    UIButton *jobsSubtitleButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    [jobsSubtitleButton setSelected:!jobsSubtitleButton.selected];
    [jobsViewController setClickType:YES]; /*** LINE 172 ***/
    if(![jobsViewController isSearching]) {
        [jobsViewController setIsSearching:YES];
        if([jobsViewController clickType]) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(reloadJobs) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];             
        } else {
            [self performSelector:@selector(reloadJobs) withObject:nil];    
        }   
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is ```jobsViewController``` initialized?

Comment: jobsViewController is initialized in initWithFrame:frame method, the touchUp method is called by 4 buttons witch can be all at same time, I've made a simple change, setClickType YES only if clickType is NO. can be for this? Thanks

Comment: If you are able to recreate this crash, can you determine the value of jobsViewController as seen in the debugger when the crash has occurred?  The case seems like that pointer might be incorrect during the crash scenario.

Comment: I create an Assert to check if jobsViewController is nil and put just before the line (172) where occurs the error `NSAssert(jobsViewController != nil, @"ERROR: jobsViewController IS NIL");`

Comment: And this to checj if instance is kinf of JobsVIewController `NSAssert([jobsViewController isKindOfClass:[JobsViewController class]], @"jobsViewController is not JobsViewController class");`

Comment: thanks @Heath Hunnicutt i fixed de problem, the problem is in my custom `UITableViewCell` that also use `jobsViewController` an when is `autorelease` also `release` the `jobsViewController`, and that results in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough code to make the root cause of the problem clear. The crash happens because the jobsViewController ivar in your object points to an object that has already been deallocated. But why was it deallocated at this point? There is no way to know based on this code. The most likely cause is that you forgot to retain it or the property was not declared as "retain". But, there could be a number of programming mistakes that were the root cause. You will need to do a code review looking specifically for problems related to not retaining the object pointed to by jobsViewController.